# Which one is correct about calling a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a code in JavaScript shown below: in this code, onClick button wants to call function `fadetext()`, and the function `fadetext()` itself setTimeout.

```js
hex = 255 // Initial color value.
function fadetext()
{
  if (hex > 0) { //If color is not black yet
    hex -= 11; // increase color darkness
    document.getElementById("sample").style.color = "rgb(" + hex + "," + hex + "," + hex + ")";
    setTimeout(fadetext, 20);
  }
  else hex = 255 //reset hex value   
}
```

```html
<div id="sample" style="width:100%">
  <h3>John slowly faded into view</h3>
</div>
<button onClick=fadetext()>Fade Text</button>
```

However, when I refer to the answer, the differences are shown in the following two lines of codes:

```
setTimeout("fadetext()",20);
```

Another one is:

```
<button onClick="fadetext()">Fade Text</button>
```

Could somebody helps me to explain why this also works?

Comment: @phuzi but setTimeout("fadetext()",20);  also works

Comment: @DempsyZhou see the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout, the string version is not recommended for the same reason that `eval()` is a security risk. Although it works, don't use it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes a reference to a function that should be called when the timeout expires, not a string.

*Although `setTimeout` can take a string that is `eval`d,* ***do not use it***, *it's a security risk in the same way that `eval()` is.*

`setTimeout("fadetext()",20);` should be `setTimeout(fadetext,20);`

and the `onclick` attribute is all lowercase.

`<button onClick="fadetext()">Fade Text</button>` should be `<button onclick="fadetext()">Fade Text</button>`

```js
var hex = 255 // Initial color value.

function fadetext() {
  if (hex > 0) { //If color is not black yet
    hex -= 11; // increase color darkness
    document.getElementById("sample").style.color = "rgb(" + hex + "," + hex + "," + hex + ")";
    setTimeout(fadetext, 20);
  } else hex = 255 //reset hex value   
}
```

```html
<div id="sample" style="width:100%">
  <h3>John slowly faded into view</h3>
</div>
<button onclick="fadetext()">Fade Text</button>
```